# Timer for parallel controllers in jmeter

Tags: controller, jmeter, load-testing

I need to add the time delay of 5 sec only in my child request(In the attached screenshot i want to add 5 min delay for req 2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11) which are in parallel controller. Can some one suggest the timer that i need to use in Jmeter.[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Lwj.png)

Answer (score 0):

If this is really what you want:

JMeter timers obey [JMeter scoping rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so if you want to introduce a delay before executing a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - add a [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) as a child of this Sampler and put `return 5000` into "Script" area

[image]

JMeter will wait for the defined time (in the above case - for 5 seconds) before executing it.

[image]

---

However if you need to "sleep" for some time before this or that request - it's quite enough just to move them outside the Parallel Controller